# How to remove word after special charcter from string using PHP

Tags: php

I need to remove some value from string using PHP. Here is my code:

```
$data=['abcgh \\200ub','ascdvb\ 15.02','fgtrmky']
```

Here I need to remove the word `200ub` with slash only where it will present not from all string.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php something like this?

Comment: Please show us what you expect the results to be and what you've tried.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1):

Using `for` loop to find first the string, then change it by replacing `str_replace`

```
$data=['abcgh \\200ub','ascdvb\ 15.02','fgtrmky'];
for($i=0;$i< count($data); $i++)
{
 if(strrpos($data[$i], "200ub"))
 {
   $data[$i] = str_replace("\\200ub","", $data[$i]);
 }
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: it may be come in any position. i need to check every string and remove.

Comment: So just do this with a foreach loop: `foreach($data as $string)`

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @satya then you should make that clear in your question along with what you expect the results to be.

Comment: @satya check out my answer, I did something optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Make a foreach to loop through every index in your array. Then replace your string with "" (nothing).

```
$data=['abcgh \\200ub','ascdvb\ 15.02','fgtrmky'];

$i = 0;
foreach($data as $string) {
    $data[$i++] = str_replace("\\200ub","", $string);
}
```

Or to remove both backslashes with it:

```
$data[$i++] = str_replace("\\\\200ub","", $string);
```

Comment: A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php 
$data=['abcgh \\200ub','ascdvb\ 15.02','fgtrmky'];
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    /*Here we are looping through array and check whether 200ub is present or not*/
    $result = stripos($data[$i],"200ub");
    /*If data is present we will replace that string with blank one*/
    if($result!=""){
        $data[$i]=str_replace("\\200ub","",$data[$i]);
    }
}
print_r($data);

?>
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: ok thanks i will try to explain my answer as much as possible

Comment: @Shaunak : it should also remove both slashes.

Comment: @satya Check my answer, maybe you need 4 backslashes to remove both backslashes because the backslash is the escape char